# How do/can I retrieve text data from a Twitter account in Python

Tags: python, text, twitter

I want to retrieve the text data for a specific twitter account and save it for a ML project about text generation, is this possible using the Twitter API?

Comment: Have you tried [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Try tweepy. It is a wrapper for Twitter API.